# Automapper: Nested Properties w/ filter to Flattened ViewModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have an EF entity that looks like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int IdCustomer {get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    ICollection<Specialty> Specialties {get;private set;}
}

public class Specialty
{
    public int IdSpecialty {get;private set}
    public int? IdSpecTypeOne {get;private set;}
    public int? IdSpecTypeTwo {get;private set;}
    public string Name {get;private set;}

    public virtual SpecTypeOne SpecialtyTypeOne {get;private set;}
    public virtual SpecTypeTwo SpecialtyTypeOne {get;private set;}
}

public class SpecTypeOne
{
    public int IdSpecTypeOne {get;private set;}
    public string Name {get;private set;}
}

public class SpecTypeTwo
{
    public int IdSpecTypeTwo {get;private set;}
    public string Name {get;private set;}
}
```

and a ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public int IdCustomer
  public List<CustomerSpecialtyViewModel> SpecialtyOfTypeOne {get; set;}
  public List<CustomerSpecialtyViewModel> SpecialtyOfTypeTwo {get;set;}
}

public class CustomerSpecialtyViewModel
{
  public int IdSpecialty {get;set;}
  public int IdSpecTypeOne {get;set;}
  public int IdSpecTypeTwo {get;set;}
  public string SpecTypeName {get;set;}
}
```

Basically, I want to build my ViewModel like above, flattening *Specialty* and *SpecType* to a single ViewModel (*CustomerSpecialtyViewModel*).

I'm mapping the ViewModel as:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Specialty, CustomerSpecialtyViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>()
  .ForMember(d => d.SpecialtyOfTypeOne, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Specialties.Where(p => p.IdSpecType == SpecTypes.TypeOne)))
  .ForMember(d => d.SpecialtyOfTypeTwo, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Specialties.Where(p => p.IdSpecType == SpecTypes.TypeTwo)))
```

How I can include the sub-property **SpecType.Name** in *CustomerSpecialtyViewModel*, since this is a **sub-property**?

```
CustomerSpecialtyViewModel
{
     int IdSpecialty => OK
     int IdSpecType => OK
     string SpecTypeName => Getting 'NULL' - Need this
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have TWO types of SpecType (One and Two), but both have a common property (Name). I only need the property. I´ll check what type is (One or Two) internally in my Application Service. In the context of View, this doesn´t matter.

Comment: I'm surprised that `SpecialtyName` works. I'd expect just `Name` and `SpecialtyTypeName` (in `CustomerSpecialtyViewModel`) to work in flattening.

Comment: Gert, i´ve updated my scenario. You right, in that way, SpecialtyName didn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Specialty, CustomerSpecialtyViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.SpecTypeName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SpecialtyType.Name));
```

Comment: Hi Patrick. I´ve updated my scenario to be a little differente. Sorry for the error. I think you can help me =)

Comment: I think you just need to put similar, conditional logic in the mapping for SpecTypeName (like you did when determining how to map SpecialtyOfTypeOne and SpecialtyOfTypeTwo).